# Multi Form Jquery Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ok, so I have a jquery form that has a few different fieldsets. I use jquery to switch in between from each one and eventually it leads to a submit button. Can someone edit my jfiddle or provide me code on how I can submit this data via javascript, jquery, ajax.
**http://jsfiddle.net/y93sL15t/**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

Theres an example of part. Please go to jfiddle to see the whole thing

Theres a link to all of my code.
I have the submit button function ready, I just need someone to help me fill it so I can send the info from the form, to an email address. Please provide full code, no code that is like Function() "put code here". Thanks

Comment: -1 "Please provide full code, no code that is like Function() "put code here"." - **so we need to do the work for you??** In here you learn what you did wrong so you can continue, we don't do homework!

Comment: im sorry, didn't mean to sound like that, but it isn't homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside submit click function, before return false, you can write submit the form like this:

```
// works as "real" form submit using form name fields
$('#msform').submit();
```

Comment: how would I take that and submit it so it sends it to an email address?

Comment: You will need PHP (.NET, ect) to achieve that. This might help: [link](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-form-to-email.html)

Comment: yea, i figured out by what you meant.  Thanks so much. Your actually the first person to help me. A simple yet so hard answer lol. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I when I tested it first, it did work through mybrowser where i push submit and it took me to the php file. Now I put it on xampp and it wont submit. Do you think its just xampp or do you think there isa reason?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting any errors? When you tested it in your browser, was it locally on your machine without xampp?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. I tested it locally without xampp. I know php doesn't run but Iwas seeing if the submit button worked to go that php page. Which it does. But when I run it with xampp, it wont work. I'll just click submit any nothing

Comment: Actually. It works now. I found that i had a required tag in one of the fields so when I would randomly type something incorrect, it woudn't submit it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.serialize()` helper ([see doc](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) to transform your `form` inputs to a `string` and any Ajax method like `$.post(…)`:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(data, status, jqXhr) {

    });
    return false;
})
```